# Checking if a string's characters are ascending alphabetically and its ascent is evenly spaced python

Tags: python

So need to check if a string's characters are ascending alphabetically and if that ascent is evenly spaced.

```
a = "abc"
b = "ceg"
```

So a is alphabetically ascending and it's spacing is 1 (if you convert to the ordinal values they are 97,98,99). And b is also alphabetically ascending and it's spacing is 2 (99,101,103).

And I am sticking with the following code:

```
a = 'jubjub'
words1 = []
ords = [ord(letter) for letter in a]
diff = ords[1] - ords[0]
for ord_val in range(1, len(ords)-1):
    if diff > 0:
        if ords[ord_val + 1] - ords[ord_val] == diff:
            if a not in words1:
                words1.append((a, diff))
print words1
```

How come 'jubjub' works, 'ace' works, but 'catcat' doesn't?

Comment: yes, can't you answer homework questions, or at least guide me in the right direction??

Comment: Sure, but you should use the homework tag

Comment: if only i'd have known, i'm a newbie

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> from string import lowercase
>>> a="abc"
>>> any(a in lowercase[i::j+1] for i,j in product(range(26),repeat=2))
True
>>> b="ceg"
>>> any(b in lowercase[i::j+1] for i,j in product(range(26),repeat=2))
True
>>> c="longer"
>>> any(c in string.lowercase[i::j+1] for i,j in product(range(26),repeat=2))
False
>>> d="bdfhj"
>>> any(d in string.lowercase[i::j+1] for i,j in product(range(26),repeat=2))
True
```

It's not necessary to use product, and a little more efficient to do it this way

```
>>> any(a in string.lowercase[i::j+1] for i in range(26) for j in range(26-i))
True
```

Comment: can i ask, what is the significance of the range(25), and also is the repeat= 2 because there are 3 letters? i am talking if I had a string of arbitrary length with an arbitrary letter spacing, how would i test for that

Comment: @FRU5TR8EDD, exactly the same way, try it and you will see

Comment: @FRU5TR8EDD, I've added a way that doesn't use `product` or `repeat`

Answer (score 2):

without itertools

```
>>> a = 'abc'
>>> ords = [ord(c) for c in a]
>>> ords == sorted(ords)
True

>>> diffs = set()
>>> for i in range(len(ords) -1): diffs.add(ords[i] - ords[i+1])
>>> len(diffs) == 1
True
```

Comment: The first bit is perfect, way more efficient than what i've been using, however the second bit ain't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: it says: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: fixed it, should have been `add` instead of `append`

Comment: my problem again is that it shows me:
>>> for i in range(len(ords) -1): diffs.add(ords[i] - ords[i+1])
...

Not
>>> for i in range(len(ords) -1): diffs.add(ords[i] - ords[i+1])
>>>

Please explain

Comment: Instead of bothering with a set, you could also do `diff = ords[1] - ords[0]; all(ords[i+1] - ords[i] == diff for i in range(1, len(ords)-1)`. Or, without explicit indices, `all(snd - first == diff for first, snd in zip(ords, ords[1:]))`.

Comment: Thanks @Dougal, but how do I implement your code, if i put in:
>>> diff = ords[1] - ords[0]; all(ords[i+1] - ords[i] == diff for i in range(1, len(ords)-1)
...
What do I type in afterwards??

Comment: The call to `all` will return a boolean that tells you whether they're all the same. If you're doing this in the shell, it should just print it out for you; otherwise you can assign it to a variable or print it normally or whatever. It works by running that `==` call in there for each value of `i` (like the list comprehension used in other answers, but this is a generator comprehension that doesn't actually create the list). If any of the `==` calls return `False`, `all` will stop and return `False`; if they all succeed, it returns `True`.

Answer (score 1):

only hints for home work,,,

you can try to make use of something from this

```
In [100]: z = 'abc'
In [101]: [ord(x) for x in z]
Out[101]: [97, 98, 99]
```

then there can be several logics to check if the elements are evenly spaced :)

Answer (score 1):

A non intuitive approach in handling this

```
>>> somestring = "aceg"
>>> len(set([ord(y)-ord(x) for (x,y) in zip(*(iter(somestring),) * 2) if y > x]))==1
True
```

The concept is to create the difference of subsequent element and see if the difference is consistent. For that I create a set and determine if the length is `1` in which case the order is preserved. Also to ensure that the series

Comment: I don't think this is right, it also returns `True` for `"axcy"` You need `zip(somestring, somestring[1:])` or similar. Even then, you are only adding to the set when y>x, so if letters are out of sequence you will just be ignoring the difference between them