# from a list of strings, how do you get a tuple/list of words which contain 3 or more characters and are evenly spaced in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking if a string's characters are ascending alphabetically and its ascent is evenly spaced python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922436/checking-if-a-strings-characters-are-ascending-alphabetically-and-its-ascent-is)

I have a list of strings/words:

```
mylist = ['twas', 'brillig', 'and', 'the', 'slithy', 'toves', 'did', 'gyre', 'and', 'gimble', 'in', 'the', 'wabe', 'all', 'mimsy', 'were', 'the', 'borogoves', 'and', 'the', 'mome', 'raths', 'outgrabe', '"beware', 'the', 'jabberwock', 'my', 'son', 'the', 'jaws', 'that', 'bite', 'the', 'claws', 'that', 'catch', 'beware', 'the', 'jubjub', 'bird', 'and', 'shun', 'the', 'frumious', 'bandersnatch', 'he', 'took', 'his', 'vorpal', 'sword', 'in', 'hand', 'long', 'time', 'the', 'manxome', 'foe', 'he', 'sought', 'so', 'rested', 'he', 'by', 'the', 'tumtum', 'tree', 'and', 'stood', 'awhile', 'in', 'thought', 'and', 'as', 'in', 'uffish', 'thought', 'he', 'stood', 'the', 'jabberwock', 'with', 'eyes', 'of', 'flame', 'came', 'whiffling', 'through', 'the', 'tulgey', 'wood', 'and', 'burbled', 'as', 'it', 'came', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'and', 'through', 'and', 'through', 'the', 'vorpal', 'blade', 'went', 'snicker-snack', 'he', 'left', 'it', 'dead', 'and', 'with', 'its', 'head', 'he', 'went', 'galumphing', 'back', '"and', 'has', 'thou', 'slain', 'the', 'jabberwock', 'come', 'to', 'my', 'arms', 'my', 'beamish', 'boy', 'o', 'frabjous', 'day', 'callooh', 'callay', 'he', 'chortled', 'in', 'his', 'joy', '`twas', 'brillig', 'and', 'the', 'slithy', 'toves', 'did', 'gyre', 'and', 'gimble', 'in', 'the', 'wabe', 'all', 'mimsy', 'were', 'the', 'borogoves', 'and', 'the', 'mome', 'raths', 'outgrabe']
```

firstly i need to only get the words which have 3 or more characters in them - i assume a for loop for that or something.
then i need to get a list of words which contain only words that increase from left to right alphabetically and are a fixed number apart. (e.g. ('ace', 2) or ('ceg', 2) does not have to be 2) the list also has to be sorted in alphabetical order and each element should be a tuple consisting of the word and character difference.

I think i have to use a for loop but im not sure how to use it in this case and am not sure how to do the second part.

for the list above the answer i should get is:

```
([])
```

I do not have the newest version of python.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should choose a test vector that will actually give you a useful result to test for...

Comment: not much really, dont really know how to start

Comment: You've asked a number of questions now without showing any code. While we like to help, you need to start to learn how to do these things on your own. Also, if these are homework questions, please tag them `homework` as well as `python`.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start by learning how to use a [for loop](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). A for loop will get things out of a collection and assign them to a variable:

```
for letter in "strings are collections":
    print letter
```

Or..

```
for thing in ['this is a list', 'of', 4, 'things']:
    if thing == 4:
        print '4 is in the list'
```

If you're able to do more than this, then try something, figure out where you get stuck, and ask as more specifically what you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Take this problem in steps

1. To filter words with length >= 3

   `[w for w in mylist if len(w) >= 3]`
2. To see if the words are increasing in regular interval? Calculate the difference, between consecutive letters, create a set and check if the length == 1

   `diff =lambda word:len({ord(n)-ord(c) for n,c in zip(word[1:],word)}) == 1`
3. Now use this new function to filter the remaining words

   `[w for w in mylist if len(w) >= 3 and diff(w)]`

Comment: when you create a set and check if the length is == 1, how would u make it so it checks for 2 and 3 and so on. as in check for a difference of 2 and 3, etc???