# Python: How would i write this 'if' statement for a word of arbitrary length?

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking if a string's characters are ascending alphabetically and its ascent is evenly spaced python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922436/checking-if-a-strings-characters-are-ascending-alphabetically-and-its-ascent-is)

This is what I currently have:

```
wordlist = ['fox', 'aced', 'definite', 'ace']

for word in wordlist:
    a = len(word)
    if (ord(word[a-(a-1)] - ord(word[(a-a)])) == ord(word[a-(a-2)])-ord(word[a-(a-1)]:
        print "success", word
    else:
        print "fail", word
```

What I'm trying to do is calculate the ASCII values between each of the letters in the word. And check to see if the ord of the letters are increasing by the same value.

so for fox, it would check if the difference between the ord of 2nd and 1st letters are equal to the ord difference of the 3rd and 2nd letters.

However, with my current 'if' statement, only the first 3 letters of a word are compared. How can I rewrite this statement to cover every letter in a word of length greater than 3?

Sorry if I can't present this clearly, thanks for your time.

Comment: You're overcomplicating this. Just loop over the letters of the word.

Comment: `word[ a - (a-1) ]` is same as `word[1]`

Comment: Do you only want ascending letters?

Answer (score 1):

Note the use of `len(set(...)) < 2`:

```
def check(word):
    return len(set(ord(a) - ord(b) for a,b in zip(word,word[1:]))) < 2

wordlist = ['fox', 'aced', 'definite', 'ace']
print filter(check, wordlist)
```

Prints:

```
['fox', 'ace']
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
import operator

def diff(s):
    return map(operator.sub, s[1:], s[:-1])

wordlist = ['fox', 'aced', 'definite', 'ace']
print [w for w in wordlist if len(set(diff(map(ord, w)))) == 1]

## ['fox', 'ace']
```

The latter expression decomposed:

```
w = 'fox'
print map(ord, w) # [102, 111, 120]
print diff(map(ord, w)) # [9, 9]
print set(diff(map(ord, w))) # set([9])
print len(set(diff(map(ord, w)))) # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
wordlist = ['fox', 'aced', 'definite', 'ace', 'x']

for word in wordlist:
    if len(word) < 2:
        print "fail", word
        continue
    diff = ord(word[1]) - ord(word[0])
    if all(ord(word[i+1])-ord(word[i])==diff for i in xrange(1, len(word)-1)):
        print "success", word
    else:
        print "fail", word
```

Notice that this solution is efficient, as it doesn't generate any intermediate lists or word slices and the processing inside `all()` is done with iterators, also `all()` is "short-circuiting": it will terminate on the first `False` it finds.

Comment: Doesn't  work if the word is `'a'`

Comment: We're talking about _differences_ of characters here, if there's only one character, there's nothing to do.

Comment: But he said strings of arbitrary length so i expected that to go anything from 1 and above.

Comment: @jamylak oh, well. I edited my answer with one extra case for very short words.

Comment: Your reasoning makes sense though and the question is vague, also it is a duplicate I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to see of the ord difference between every letter in a word is the same.

```
def check(word):
    return all((ord(ele_1) - ord(ele_2)) == (ord(word[0]) - ord(word[1])) for ele_1,ele_2 in zip(word,word[1:]) )
```

Result:

```
>>> check('abcde')
True
>>> check('wdjhrd')
False
```

Applying to your list:

```
wordlist = ['fox', 'aced', 'definite', 'ace']

new_list = filter(check, wordlist)
```

Result:

```
>>> new_list
['fox', 'ace']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my form which I feel is a little more readable and extendable into a list comprehension.

```
>>> a = 'ace'
>>> all(ord(a[n])-ord(a[n-1]) == (ord(a[1])-ord(a[0])) for n in xrange(len(a)-1,0,-1))
True
```

and to iterate through the list of words, a list comprehension:

```
wordlist = ['fox', 'aced', 'definite', 'ace']
[a for a in wordlist if all(ord(a[n])-ord(a[n-1]) == (ord(a[1])-ord(a[0])) for n in xrange(len(a) -1,0,-1))]
```

Returns:

```
['fox', 'ace']
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try changing the `ord(word[a-(a-2)])` to `ord(word[a-(a-len((word)-1))])`. I'm not sure if that's your exact code, but it seems to also be some EOF errors.

Comment: -1: this does not work for strings of arbitrary length - as wanted.